# С# Делегат указывающий не метод с разными параметрами

Tags: c#, методы, делегаты

Есть чат в котором идет регистрация команд таким методом:

```
chat.regCmd("getWeapon", weapon.getWeapon);

//Chat.cs
public delegate void CmdCallback(IPlayer player, object[] args);;

private Dictionary<string, CmdCallback> cmdDic = new Dictionary<string, CmdCallback>();

public async Task regCmd(String nameCmd, CmdCallback callback)
{
    cmdDic.Add(nameCmd, callback);
}

private void invokeCmd(IPlayer player, String cmd, object[] args)
{
    if (cmdDic.ContainsKey(cmd))
    {
        cmdDic[cmd](player, args);
    }
    else
    {
        emitAddMessage(player, true, "Command not found");
    }
}

//Weapon.cs 
public void getWeapon(IPlayer player, object[] args)
{
    try
    {
        string nameWeapon = (string)args[1];
        int ammoCount = int.Parse((string)args[2]);

        player.GiveWeaponAsync(nameWeapon, ammoCount, true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        chat.emitAddMessage(player, true, "/getWeapon [NameWeapon] [Ammo]");
    }
}
```

По итогу выходит что много команд ссылаются на методы с одинаковыми параметрами где в `object[] args` передаются их параметры и внутри метода идет их получение.

Как можно привести к такому типу как:

```
getWeapon(string nameWeapon, int ammoCount);
```

грубо говоря указывать в методе уже необходимые параметры и добавить прослойку которая будет перед вызовом метода команды проверять `args` на наличие необходимых параметров и в противном случае сразу возвращать ответ чтобы убрать в каждом методе `try/catch`.

Comment: **Я не уверен, что верно понял задачу**, но вроде вы ищите это:

    `public void getWeapon(IPlayer player, string nameWeapon, int ammoCount) =>
        getWeapon(player, new object[]{nameWeapon, ammoCount});`

Comment: Ну вы в сигнатуре указали `object[] args`, так и передавайте `new object[]{true, "Commamd not found"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужно делегату задавать параметры, пусть он сам определит что и как.

Допустим я создам такой простенький класс:

```
class CommandsManager
{
    public Dictionary<string, Delegate> Commands = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();

    public void Register(string command, Delegate action)
        => Commands.Add(command, action);

    public Delegate Command(string commandName)
    {
        if (!Commands.ContainsKey(commandName))
            throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Команда '{commandName}' не найдена!");
        return Commands[commandName];
    }

    public void Invoke(string commandName, object[] args = default)
    {
        try
        {
            Command(commandName).DynamicInvoke(args);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Как видите у меня простой `Dictionary<string, Delegate>`, делегат которого не содержит какую либо дополнительную информацию. В `Invoke` я у нужной команды вызываю метод `.DynamicInvoke(args)`, который сам подставит нужные параметры и выдаст нам результат. Что бы программа не падала, обернул все в `try/catch` с выводом ошибки на экран консоли.

Ну и теперь использование:

```
private static CommandsManager Manager = new CommandsManager();
```

Создадим два метода, которые что то будут делать:

```
public static void GetWeapon(string name, int ammoCount) 
    => Console.WriteLine($"Вызвана команда 'GetWeapon'\nПараметры: Name: {name} AmmoCount: {ammoCount}");

public static void GetUserInfo() 
    => Console.WriteLine("Ник: User\nКласс: Маг\nУровень: 999");
```

Регистрируем их:

```
Manager.Register("/getweapon", new Action<string, int>(GetWeapon));
Manager.Register("/userinfo", new Action(GetUserInfo));
```

И вызываем:

```
Manager.Invoke("/getweapon", new object[] { "Клинок бури", 22 });
Console.WriteLine();
Manager.Invoke("/getweapon", new object[] { 123 });
Console.WriteLine();
Manager.Invoke("/userinfo");
Console.WriteLine();
Manager.Invoke("/test");
```

Результатом будет следующее:

```
Вызвана команда 'GetWeapon'
Параметры: Name: Клинок бури AmmoCount: 22

Несоответствие числа параметров.

Ник: User
Класс: Маг
Уровень: 999

Команда '/test' не найдена!
```

Как видите, все отработало так, как и должно. Осталось "допилить" это все и думаю будет вполне годный вариант.