# Как реализовать ввод пользователя в Telegram Bot`e на C# в равзветвлении Swich?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Пишу телеграм бота. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
    Команды пользователя обрабатываю с помощью Swich Case. Понадобилось сдлеать разветвление. Когда пользователь выбирает команду "/Teachers" то бот просит его ввести Фамилию преподавателя, и выдаёт инфу о нём, а если такой фамилии нету, то выскакивает исключение.

```
 private static async void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs e)
        {     
            if (e.Message == null || e.Message.Type != MessageType.Text) return;

            switch (e.Message.Text.Split(' ').First())
            {
                case "/News": //Новинки происходящие на факультете
                    await botClient.SendChatActionAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.UploadPhoto);
                    const string News = @"**********";
                    var news = News.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last();
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(News, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                    {
                        await botClient.SendPhotoAsync(
                            e.Message.Chat.Id,
                            fileStream);
                    }
                    break;                
                case "/PairSchedule": //Расписание занятий
                    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "По этой ссылке вы можете детально ознакомиться с рассписанием занятий:\n" +
                    "********");
                    break;                               
                case "/Teachers":
                    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "Введите фамилию преподавателя: ");                  
                    if (e.Message.Text.Split(' ').First() == "Басараб")
                    {
                        await botClient.SendChatActionAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.UploadPhoto);
                        const string Bas = @"**********";
                        var pr1 = News.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last();
                        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Bas, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                        {
                            await botClient.SendPhotoAsync(
                                e.Message.Chat.Id,
                                fileStream);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (e.Message.Text.Split(' ').First() == "Ткаченко")
                    {

                    }
                    else if (e.Message.Text.Split(' ').First() == "Миловидов")
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "Вы ввели не правильную фамилию, или такого преподавателя нету!");
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, @"Доступные команды:
/News Новости факультета
/PairSchedule Рассписание занятий.
/Teachers преподаватели факультета.
                    ");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вам нравиться ваш код? Мне вот лично не особо... Может вам стоит сделать что то, на подобие [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1020126/220553)? Тогда ваши команды будут разбиты на отдельные методы, хоть по разным классам можете распихать их, дело ваше, тогда и логику различного рода будет там легко реализовать. А по поводу вопроса, лично мне от не понятен. Что вам мешает спросить пользователя нужные данные повторно и обработать?

Comment: Это мой первый телеграм бот. Я делаю его с помощью интернета, и это единственный способ который мне стал придельно ясен, поэтому и начал писать так криво. Я задумывался над тем что бы разбить всё по отдельным методам, но не нашел способа как это сделать. Если вы поможете поместить один кейс в метод, буду признателен. А суть вопроса в том, что бы в "case "/Teachers": "реализовать разветвление, и что бы ответы пользователя обрабатывались не в методе "Bot_OnMessage", а в этом же case