# Рисование треугольников в консоли

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Изучаю шарп, хотелось бы получить критику и советы как лучше сделать!

**Три класса**

- `Program`: Мейн класс вызывает классы Rectangle and Triangle.
- `Rectangle`: Содержит метод получение площади по двум сторонам.
- `Triangle`: Содержит методы вывода в консоль треугольников с помощью `*`

Код рабочий!

[image: Задания]

```cs
using System.Drawing;

namespace TaskOne
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program app = new Program();
            app.StartApplication();
        }

        public void StartApplication()
        {
            //getTriangle();
            GetRectangle();
        }

        public void getTriangle()
        {
            Triangle triangle = new Triangle();
            //triangle.ShowTriangle();
            //triangle.ShowAnotherTriangle();
            triangle.ShowMasTreeTriangle();


        }

        public void GetRectangle()
        {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
            //rectangle.GetMessage();
            rectangle.GetArea();
        }
    }
}

internal class Rectangle
{

    public Rectangle()
    {

    }


    public void GetArea()
    {
      
        int firstSide = GetSideLenght();
        int secondSide = GetSideLenght();

        Console.WriteLine("Площадь прямоугольника: " + (firstSide * secondSide));
      
    }

    public int GetSideLenght()
    {
        Console.Write("Введите длину стороны: ");
        int lenght = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if(lenght <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Только положительные числа отличные от нуля,попробуйте снова!");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        return lenght;
    }
}

internal class Triangle
{

    public Triangle()
    {

    }

    public void ShowTriangle()
    {
        Console.Write("Введите количество строк: ");
        int height = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public void ShowAnotherTriangle()
    {
        Console.Write("Введите количество строк: ");
        int height = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(height - i, i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j <= i * 2; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public void ShowMasTreeTriangle()
    {
        Console.Write("Введите количество строк: ");
        int height = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(height - i, i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j <= i * 2; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Читали описание метки [tag:инспекция-кода]?

Comment: @dIm0n И что тут не так?

Comment: @dIm0n может и всё так
но я бы хотел узнать 
как можно сделать лучше
если можно

Comment: @EvgeniyZ несодержательный заголовок, задание картинками и т.д. (см. описание)

Comment: @AlexNetton прочитайте описание метки и отредактируйте вопрос с помощью кнопки править

Comment: @dIm0n Ну так подправьте заголовок, если он вам не нравиться. Человек пришел с полностью рабочим кодом, попросил посмотреть, правильно-ли он написал все, может можно иначе, дал задание по которому он это написал, поставил инспецию кода, но нет, получает минусы, за что? Где тут несогласование с инспекцией то?

Comment: Сорри
я второй день тут
могу делать ошибки

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я написал конкретные пункты, всё есть по ссылкам https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/инспекция-кода/info и [ask]

Comment: @AlexNetton не надо передо мной извиняться :D. Просто улучшите качество вопроса, вот [кнопка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1171220/edit)

Comment: @dIm0n Я говорю, что если видите косяк, то напишите об этом автору напрямую, либо исправьте сами. Если взять ваш первый комментарий, то совершенно не понятно в чем проблема. Смотрим метку: `Наличие реального работающего кода` - есть, `Содержательный заголовок` и `Отсутствие избыточных слов в заголовке` - есть небольшой косяк, который каждый без труда может исправить. `Указание назначения кода` - есть, `Описание, откуда этот код взялся` - думаю это вовсе лишнее. Так как ваш первый комментарий указывает на ошибки в вопросе? Вот сейчас закроют вопрос и? Поймет автор что от него хотят?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ *"Я говорю, что если видите косяк, то напишите об этом автору напрямую, либо исправьте сами. Если взять ваш первый комментарий, то совершенно не понятно в чем проблема."* — я и написал ему первым комментарием, это вопрос, а не проблема; *"каждый без труда может исправить"* — в этом и смысл, чтобы он исправил; *"думаю это вовсе лишнее"* — предложите правку метки/создайте обсуждение на мете; ответы на следующие три вопроса: 1) это не указание ошибок, а вопрос; 2) будет закрыт, пока не переоткроют; 3) зависит от ТС

Comment: @dIm0n `я и написал ему первым комментарием, это вопрос, а не проблема` - с огромным намеком на то, что у него есть "косяк", а какой - пусть сам гадает. `в этом и смысл, чтобы он исправил` - на SO не просто так у всех есть механизм редактирования. Автор вон исправил по вашим наводкам вопрос, нравиться? `предложите правку метки` - в описание метке не правила, а рекомендации, зачем вам знать очевидные вещи? Написал автор сам код, и? Вам даст это что либо? `пока не переоткроют` - тут очень редко переоткрывают. `зависит от ТС` - и от нас тоже. Короче спорить с вами не буду, парня лишь жалко.

Comment: Коллеги, этой дтскуссии место на мете, она не относится к вопросу. \

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вот вы пишете "есть небольшой косяк, который каждый без труда может исправить", однако же не исправляете сами .. Что касается закрытия - стоит напомнить, что закрытие - это сначала "требует правки" - явное указание ТС что с вопросом не так и возможность правки-переоткрытия. *некропостинг закончен))

Comment: @Kromster Не работает такая система как "закрытие" и "переоткрытие" на SO! Могу кучу вопросов дать, которые имеют уйму проблем (от дубликатов, до банального "не закрыта скобка"), но чтот их не закрывают (если они только не слишком явные нарушения имеют и не режут дико сообществу глаза). Конкретно в этом случае, человек пришел с нормальным вопросом, попросил помощь, а ему сразу накидали минусов, пытаясь закрыть как "непонятный" (вроде), и вот что тут "непонятного"? Выше вон вообще говорят, что он инспекцию нарушает, только вот где..? Короче, этому вопросу не дали какого-либо шанса изначально.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ система работает, если ей систематически пользоваться. Кучу вопросов можете дать - вы на них на всех правку и/или комментарий и/или минус и/или флаг оставили? ;-) Конкретно про этот вопрос - давайте вместе почитаем описание метки и текст с картинок .. уже достаточно для минуса как мне (и другим) кажется. А шанс - даден, и плюсов отсыпано, и ответ хороший )

Comment: @Kromster `если ей систематически пользоваться` - Посмотрите мой вопрос на мете, увидите, что большинство людей советуют просто пройти мимо и закрывать на многое глаза, ведь это "хорошо раскрученный форум", где каждый заходит почитать темку после тяжелой работы, без напряга и другой ерунды. `Кучу вопросов можете дать` - не поверите, на все ставил голос, писал в комментарии, где это уместно, в итоге либо 1 голос висит, либо виси 4 и вопрос не закрывают. `Конкретно про этот вопрос` - на месте автора, увидев, что вопрос заминусовали, я бы свалил с SO, забыв про него как про ужасную помойку.

Comment: @Kromster Короче, у вас есть своя голова на плечах, у меня своя, у нас с вами свое видение ситуации, а конкретно в этом случае, парня изначально просто заминусовали, без каких-либо объяснений и тут я вам уже сказал выше, на его месте я бы расценил это весьма негативно. И спрашивается, стоило-ли нам так поступать? Может стоило бы объяснить, может как-то поправить вопрос, а не тупо кидать голос и закрывать? В общем, дальше спорить на эту тему не вижу смысла, тем более на SO, где всем на подобное плевать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое что я заметил, это то что не выполнено условие "игнорировать неверный ввод", в вашем случае приложение падает с исключением `FormatException`, если пользователь введет не число.

#### 1. Безотказный ввод числа

Чтобы реализовать "безотказный" ввод числе с клавиатуры, я предлагаю создать вот такой вспомогательный класс.

*Обратите внимание: в C# проектах принято каждый класс помещать в отдельный файл.*

**ConsoleHelper.cs**

```csharp
internal static class ConsoleHelper
{
    public static int ReadNumber(string prompt, Predicate<int> condition, string errorMessage)
    {
        int result;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(prompt);
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) && condition(result))
                break;
            Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Данный класс является статическим, потому что ему ничего не надо в себе хранить, и он не взаимодействует с другими внешними нестатическими объектами.

Для одновременной проверки и чтения числа используется метод [`int.TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8), который возвращает `true`, если преобразование строки в `int` успешно, и `false`, если нет. В случае успешного преобразования он одновоременно возвращает и само число через `out` аргумент. Получается 2 в 1.

Из нового и незнакомого здесь используется `Predicate<in T>`. **Предикат** - это метод в форме выражения, возвращающего `bool` (то есть логического выражения), в который передается какой-то аргумент, а нашем случае `int`. Подробнее о предикатах можно прочитать [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netframework-4.8).

#### 2. Реализация задания

Много кто начинает обучение с консоли, работает со строками, но почему-то мало кто в курсе, что у класса `string` есть конструкторы, всего 8 перегрузок. В данном случае очень полезной оказалась вот [эта перегрузка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_). Она позволяет создать строку заданной длины, заполненную указанным символом. Это позволит избежать лишних циклов и сделает код проще.

Я переписал классы задания с использованием выше показанного консольного помощника и конструктора `string (char c, int count)`.

*Кстати, если конструктор класса пустой, его можно не указывать. Я убрал пустые конструкторы.*

**Rectangle.cs**

```csharp
internal class Rectangle
{
    public void GetArea()
    {
        const string errorMessage = "Допустимы только положительные числа, попробуйте снова.";
        int width = ConsoleHelper.ReadNumber("Введите ширину прямоугольника: ", x => x > 0, errorMessage);
        int height = ConsoleHelper.ReadNumber("Введите высоту прямоугольника: ", x => x > 0, errorMessage);

        Console.WriteLine("Площадь прямоугольника: {0}", width * height);
    }
}
```

**Triangle.cs**

```csharp
internal class Triangle
{
    private const string errorMessage = "Допустимы только положительные числа, попробуйте снова.";

    public void ShowTriangle()
    {
        int height = ConsoleHelper.ReadNumber("Введите количество строк: ", x => x > 0, errorMessage);
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new string('*', i));
        }
    }

    public void ShowAnotherTriangle()
    {
        int height = ConsoleHelper.ReadNumber("Введите количество строк: ", x => x > 0, errorMessage);
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(height - i - 1, Console.CursorTop);
            Console.WriteLine(new string('*', i * 2 + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Еще я сделал, чтобы положение курсора в консоли менялось относительно текущей строки, а не абсолютных координат экрана, с помощью свойства консоли [`CursorTop`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.cursortop?view=netframework-4.8).

#### 3. Пользовательский интерфейс

Ваше приложение никак не взаимодействует с пользователем. А чтобы изменить используемый метод, нужно редактировать код приложения, и пересобирать само приложение. Это не совсем удобно, или даже не возможно в случае, если пользователь не имеет установленных инструментов разработчика C#.

Для исправления этого, я переписал класс `Program`, добавил главное меню.

**Program.cs**

```csharp
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program app = new Program();
        app.StartApplication();
    }

    private int MainMenu()
    {
        string[] menu = new string[]
        { 
            "[1] - Rectangle", 
            "[2] - Triangle", 
            "[3] - Another Triangle", 
            "[0] - Выход",
            ""
        };
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, menu));

        return ConsoleHelper.ReadNumber("Ваш выбор: ", x => x >= 0 && x <= 3, "Введите число 0 до 3.");
    }

    public void StartApplication()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Задание 1.1" + Environment.NewLine);
        int option;
        while ((option = MainMenu()) > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            switch (option)
            {
                case 1:
                    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
                    rectangle.GetArea();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Triangle triangle = new Triangle();
                    triangle.ShowTriangle();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    triangle = new Triangle();
                    triangle.ShowAnotherTriangle();
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

В соответствии с принципом SRP в [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), я бы еще вынес меню в отдельный класс, но оставил здесь, чтобы не усложнять пример.

---

Вывод в консоль:

```
Задание 1.1

[1] - Rectangle
[2] - Triangle
[3] - Another Triangle
[0] - Выход

Ваш выбор: 1

Введите ширину прямоугольника: 10
Введите высоту прямоугольника: 15
Площадь прямоугольника: 150

[1] - Rectangle
[2] - Triangle
[3] - Another Triangle
[0] - Выход

Ваш выбор: 2

Введите количество строк: 5

*
**
***
****
*****

[1] - Rectangle
[2] - Triangle
[3] - Another Triangle
[0] - Выход

Ваш выбор: 3

Введите количество строк: 8

       *
      ***
     *****
    *******
   *********
  ***********
 *************
***************

[1] - Rectangle
[2] - Triangle
[3] - Another Triangle
[0] - Выход

Ваш выбор: 0
```

Comment: Тут наверно стоит немного про ООП и прочие базовые принципы упомянуть. Помниться был [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/983008/220553) ответ, где было хорошо показано как на примере простого консольного приложения разбить логику на классы и методы с единственной ответственностью. Также `switch` можно заменить на некую обертку, которая помогла бы сохранить это все в одном месте и вызывать в удобный момент (об этом я как-то писал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1020126/220553)), но это уже зависит как дальше будет развиваться проект, если чисто для сдачи, то `switch` самое то.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если вас не затруднит, можете отредактировать ответ, потому что я уже с мобильного, и вернусь в полноценный онлайн не скоро. На SO ужасный мобильный редактор. Про SRP конечно стоит упомянуть, а вот `switch` я бы оставил как есть. Мне и так кажется, что я перегнул с предикатом, но вменяемого варианта без него не придумал.

Comment: Хех, я и сам последнюю неделю с мобильного, так что увы)) Я думаю если автор вопроса увидит хотя бы мой комментарий, то этого будет достаточно для него, по ссылкам есть вся информация.

Comment: @AlexNetton старайтесь все-таки сами решать. Если вам помог мой ответ, отметьте его пожалуйста принятым. Галочка слева от ответа.

Comment: @aepot я стараюсь решать сам
просто есть моменты про которые я не знаю
например как конструкторы стринга
фича которую теперь постоянно буду юзать где это уместно)