# Проблема с операциями над числами в C#: соединение (конкатенация), обработка, вывод

Tags: c#

На C# нужно ввести два трехзначных числа, соединить эти два числа так чтобы, например, для ввода

```
123
456
```

вышло

```
1245
```

Я сделал почти все из этого, кроме того что у меня выводит совсем другое число, например: я ввожу 123 и 456 у меня выводит 123456, а должно быть 1245.

Вот что я сделал:

```
double a, b,a1,b1;
           Console.WriteLine("Введите первое трехзначное число");
            a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            if (a < 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ошибка");
                
                
            }
            while (a! < 100) ;

            Console.WriteLine("Введите второе трехзначное число");
            b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            if (b < 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ошибка");
                
            }
            while (b! < 100) ;
           
            b1 = b / 100;
            b1 = b / 10 % 10;
            a1 = a / 100;
            a1 = a / 10 % 10;
            a = a + b;
            b = a - b;

            a = a - b;
            
            Console.WriteLine($"{a}{b}");
```

Comment: Эээммм... Да. 3 copy-paste вопроса это норма.

Comment: Я задал вопрос по другому, поэтому я ничего не нарушаю .

Comment: И чем вас не устраивает уже данный ранее ответ? Просто замените `double` на `int`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , но у меня все таже проблема ... Выходит 123456 а мне нужно чтобы было 1235 . Помогите пожалуйста !

Comment: `Console.WriteLine($"{(int)a/10}{(int)b/10}");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задача же простая, настолько, насколько это возможно. Здесь ее можно разделить на 2 части - огранизовать безотказный ввод трехзначного числа и провести вычисления.

Я уже написал [метод безотказного ввода числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1171427/373567) на StackOverflow ранее, просто сделаю перепост.

**Безотказный ввод числа**

```csharp
public static int ReadNumber(string prompt, Predicate<int> condition, string errorMessage)
{
    int result;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) && condition(result))
            break;
        Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Собственно, сам код**

```csharp
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string errorText = "Введите число от 100 до 999.";
    int number1 = ReadNumber("Введите первое трехзначное число: ", x => x >= 100 && x <= 999, errorText);
    int number2 = ReadNumber("Введите второе трехзначное число: ", x => x >= 100 && x <= 999, errorText);

    int result = number1 / 10 * 100 + number2 / 10;

    Console.WriteLine("Результат: {0}", result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Вывод в консоль**

```
Введите первое трехзначное число: 123
Введите второе трехзначное число: 456
Результат: 1245
```

---

**Тот же самый код, только для новичка, без предикатов**

```csharp
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string errorText = "Введите число от 100 до 999.";
    int number1;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите первое трехзначное число: ");
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number1) && number1 >= 100 && number1 <= 999)
            break;
        Console.WriteLine(errorText);
    }

    int number2;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите второе трехзначное число: ");
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number2) && number2 >= 100 && number2 <= 999)
            break;
        Console.WriteLine(errorText);
    }

    int result = number1 / 10 * 100 + number2 / 10;

    Console.WriteLine("Результат: {0}", result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: А вот этот ответ хорош. Только с предикатом  как-то слишком для новичков. (как и в моес случае с дискардом, справедливости ради). С меня плюс.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы из 3-значного целого получить 2-значное, достаточно поделить его на `10`.

В вашей программе я усматриваю следующие проблемы:

1. Поскольку речь явно о целых числах, то переменные должны быть типа `int`, а не `double`.
2. Даже если допустить, что эта конструкция компилируется, то это бесконечный цикл:

   ```
   while (a! < 100) ;
   ```
3. Суть вычислений совершенно не ясна мне, и вряд ли она соответствует заданию:

   ```
   b1 = b / 100;
   b1 = b / 10 % 10;
   a1 = a / 100;
   a1 = a / 10 % 10;
   a = a + b;
   b = a - b;
   a = a - b;
   ```

Вместо этого я предлагаю следующее:

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите первое трехзначное число");
int a, b;
while (true)
{
    a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (a >= 100 && a < 1000)
    {
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("ошибка");
}

Console.WriteLine("Введите второе трехзначное число");
while (true)
{
    b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (b >= 100 && b < 1000)
    {
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("ошибка");
}

int a1 = a / 10;
int b1 = b / 10;

Console.WriteLine($"{a1}{b1}");
```

---

Если вам уже знаком процедурный стиль, то код можно упростить:

```
int NumberInput(string prompt)
{
    Console.WriteLine(prompt);
    while (true) // Итерируем до тех пор, пока введённые данные нас не устроят
    {
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var input) && input >= 100 && input < 1000)
        {
            // Введённые данные нас устраивают
            return input;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("ошибка");
    }
}

int a = NumberInput("Введите первое трехзначное число");
int b = NumberInput("Введите второе трехзначное число");

// Обрежем младшие разряды введённых чисел
int a1 = a / 10;
int b1 = b / 10;
Console.WriteLine($"{a1}{b1}");
```

Заодно и избавимся от исключений при вводе данных, не являющихся целым числом.

Comment: Спасибо бро, помог

Comment: как все сложно здесь....

Comment: @Andrew если вам здесь сложно, то я явно ошибся, нарочито сделав код максимально простым для автора вопроса (явно не знакомого пока даже с процедурным подходом) и с минимумом изменений. Впрочем, код рабочий и даже с валидацией. Технически, это хороший ответ. Причин его минусовать, кроме "а вот мне не нравится", нет. На большом SO за такой ответ я бы собрал плюса 3-4 и чекмарк. Хэшкод такой хешкод. :)

Comment: По-моему автору проще разобраться со строкой `num1.ToString().SubString(0,2) + num2.ToString().SubString(0,2);` чем с вот этой вот простыней. Так что да, код ОЧЕНЬ сложный. А еще здесь будут эксепшны в случае ввода текста :)

Comment: @Andrew и именно поэтому автор только мне и ответил благодарностью. Наверное, от того, что не смог разобраться. Так ответ верный или нет? Если верный, то минус незаслуженный. А хотя... ну зачем поддерживать авторов ответов, которые тратят своё время, помогая явным новичкам? Лучше топить их ответы. Что ж, воля ваша. ;)

Comment: Автор ответил с благодарностью потому что это был самый первый из ответов ;) Другие, вероятнее всего, он вообще не видел еще.

Comment: @Andrew насчёт исключений вы совершенно правы. Я добавил реализацию без исключений и с процедурным стилем в виде локальной функции.

Comment: снял минус за нижний блок. Стало лучше чем было.

Comment: А код компилируется? А то у меня есть некие сомнения на тему конструкции с инпутом в шарпе.... В свифте такое точно скомпилируется, а вот в шарпе не уверен

Comment: @Andrew конечно, компилируется! Я бы не позволил себе опубликовать ответ, который не проверил. Тем более, что ответ адресован новичку.

Answer (score 2):

А не проще работать с `string`?

```
int ValueA, ValueB;
int RequiredLenght = 3;
Console.WriteLine("Введите первое трехзначное число: ");
while (true) {
    ValueA = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (ValueA.ToString().Length == RequiredLenght)
        break;
    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка. Число знаков: "+ValueA.ToString().Length);
}
Console.WriteLine("Введите второе трехзначное число: ");
while (true) {
    ValueB = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (ValueB.ToString().Length == RequiredLenght)
        break;
    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка. Число знаков: "+ValueB.ToString().Length);
}
string Result = ValueA.ToString().Substring(0, 2)+ValueB.ToString().Substring(0, 2);
Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(Result));
```

Comment: До редактирования выглядело ЗНАЧИТЕЛЬНО лучше и читабельнее. Дублирующийся код нужно в отдельный метод вывести. А еще здесь куча лишник действий. Для чего стринг переводить в инт, что бы потом переводить в стринг, что бы потом переводить в инт?

Comment: С функциями лучше, чем без, спору нет =D C `string`->`int`->`string` действительно тупанул.

Comment: Ан нет, не тупанул. Надо же удостовериться, что введины цифры. Вдруг там `abc`.

Comment: нет, тупанул. Ибо можно не выходить с цикла в случае неудачного парса. А в случае удачного парса - дальше работать со стрингом. Что бы не делать лишних действий по возвращении инта в строку. Просмотри мое решение... Оно выглядит несколько читабельнее)

Comment: Нет не тупанул. Я прохраммист, я так вижу! Ты забыл ещё `-1` самой теме поставить =D

Comment: я поставил тебе сначала +1, а когда код стало сложно читать после правки, то тогда уже поставил -1. Код должен быть простым. После правки код стал плохо читаться, его сложно дебажить, а так же много лишних действий. И неинформативная ошибка)

Comment: И на тему того что "удостовериться что там введены цифры" - у тебя там выдаст эксепшн при введении не цифр, если что. То есть никакой защиты от введения не цифр здесь нет.

Answer (score 0):

Господи, как у вас все сложно.... Задача решается в 1 строку кода

```
// input/output : string
var strRez = str1.SubString(0,2) + str2.SubString(0,2);
//Лично я бы выбрал этот путь за счет читабельности
//Увидев его -- сразу понятен результат, даже, 
//если не виден контекст кода.
//Но преподавателю такой подход не понравится.


//input/output : int
var intRez = (number1 / 10) * 100 + number2 / 10;

// input: int, output: string
var strRez = $"{num1/10}{num2/10}";
```

## А если полностью все писать, то нужно что-то вроде:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var num1 = GiveMeNum("Введите ПЕРВОЕ трехзначное число");
   var num2 = GiveMeNum("Введите ВТОРОЕ трехзначное число");

   Console.WriteLine($"{num1/10}{num2/10}"); 
}

private static int GiveMeNum( string msg = ""){
    string str ="";
    int num = 0;
    
    while (str.length != 3) {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
        str = Console.ReadLine();
        
        if (!Int32.TryParse(str, out num)) { str = ""; }
    }
    return num;
}
```

UPD: Решил, все же, выпилить из ответа дискард и удалиться от решения через подстроки. Чисто что бы не пугать препода.

Comment: Ну так я о том-же

Comment: Непонятно, почему вы отклонили правку, но поправьте, тогда ваш ответ сами, пожалуйста.

Comment: @motpfofs потому что убирание 2х пробелов в коментариях кода это не та правка, которую стоит делать в чужом ответе. Реальных улучшений ответа она  не несет. Тем более что там отсутствовали кавычки еще. Если бы их добавил, то тогда бы правку принял бы ибо это улучшение кода.

Comment: В коментарии к изменениям было указано что основная причина это кавычки) И вы признаете, что это важная правка, раз сделали её сами)

Comment: тогда прошу прощения, кавычок там не увидел в правке)