# нужно запросить по очередной ввод в консоли 3х человек, вывести результат в середине консоли

Tags: c#, циклы, счетчики

Всем привет) Вот задание. Клиент хочет, чтобы сотрудники вводили данные последовательно: сначала первый сотрудник введёт все свои данные, затем второй и, наконец, третий.
Когда пользователь будет вводить данные, он может сделать ошибку и ввести, например, отрицательный рост или огромный балл по математике. Вам стоит предусмотреть этот момент.
При возникновении ошибки пользователю наверняка захочется увидеть сообщение о ней, но никак не пустой экран. В принципе почти все но не могу запросить ввод и вывод данных для 3х человек, не пойму как. Заранее спасибо)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            // объявление переменных
            String Name;
            float His, Mathem, RL;
            byte Growth, Age;
            double Mean;

            // ввод в консоли
            Console.WriteLine("Ввод данных пользователя");


            try
            {


                // ввод в консоли вручную
                Console.Write("Введите имя - "); Name = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Введите возраст - "); Age = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Введите рост - "); Growth = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



                Console.Write("\n\nВведите баллы \n");

                Console.Write("История - "); His = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                while (His >= 6 | 0 >= His)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели не правильное значение,\nданные будут не корректны!");
                    break;
                }
                Console.Write("Математика - "); Mathem = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                while (Mathem >= 6 | 0 >= Mathem)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели не правильное значение,\n данные будут не корректны!");
                    break;
                }
                Console.Write("Русский язык - "); RL = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                while (RL >= 6 | 0 >= RL)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели не правильное значение,\n данные будут не корректны!");
                    break;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка ввода!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                continue;
            }

            Mean = (His + Mathem + RL) / 3;

            //Создаём переменную с текстом, разбитым на строки с помощью \n
            string Text = "Записная книжка \n Ученик:" + Name + $" {Age} года, рост {Growth}, средний бал: " + Mean.ToString("#.##");

            //Разбиваем текст на массив строк
            string[] lines = Regex.Split(Text, "\r\n|\r|\n");

            //Отступ слева будет определяться для каждой строки отдельно
            int left = 0;
            //Определяем отступ сверху для первой строки
            int top = (Console.WindowHeight / 2) - (lines.Length / 2) - 1;

            //Находим центр консоли
            int center = Console.WindowWidth / 2;

            for (int j = 0; j < lines.Length; j++)
            {
                //Определяем отступ для текущей строки
                left = center - (lines[j].Length / 2);

                //Меняем положение курсора
                Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
                //Выводим строку
                Console.WriteLine(lines[j]);

                top = Console.CursorTop;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: [Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1177539/373567) я показывал метод безотказного ввода числа с консоли с сообщением пользователю об ошибке при некорректном вводе.

Comment: Спасибо большое