# Если ввести буквы вместо чисел нужно, чтобы вывело текст "Попробуйте еще раз"

Tags: c#

У меня есть этот код, если ввести буквы вместо цифр нужно, чтобы вывело текст "Попробуйте еще раз" и я мог еще раз ввести значение, щас у меня выводит ошибку и выбрасывает с консоли.

```
using System;

namespace _1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double x, y, z, s;
            Console.WriteLine("x:");
            x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("y:");
            y = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("z:");
            z = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            s = Math.Pow(y, Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x), 1 / 3)) + Math.Pow(Math.Cos(y), 3) * (Math.Abs(x -y) * 
                (1 + ((Math.Pow(Math.Sin(z), 2)) / (Math.Sqrt(x + y)))) / (Math.Exp(Math.Abs(x - y)) + x / 2));
            s = Math.Round(s, 3);
            Console.Write(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с операциями над числами в C#: соединение (конкатенация), обработка, вывод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1177492/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(true)
{
try
  {
   //тут твой код
  }
catch { Console.WriteLine("Попробуйте еще раз");}
}
```

Попробуй так

Comment: Спасибо, код работает

Answer (score 2):

Без всяких try-catch

```
double x;   
Console.WriteLine("X: ");
while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x))
    Console.WriteLine("Попробуйте еще раз");                
Console.WriteLine($"вы ввели {x}");
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1177539/373567