# Не могу реализовать код без goto

Tags: c#, goto

Только начал изучать с#, очень трудно даются циклы, в конкретных задачах не могу додуматься до решения с помощью цикла, из за этого использую goto, как реализовать данный код без goto?

```
a: Console.WriteLine("a = ");
try
{
    a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

}
catch (Exception)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели некорректное число! Введите еще раз число a");
    goto a;
}
```

Comment: [Просто оставлю это здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1177539/373567), на случай, если надо не просто корректно спарсить число, но еще и проверить, соответствует ли оно какому-то условию.

Comment: Предполагается ли выход из цикла?

Answer (score 8):

Первое, что пришло в голову

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("a = ");
    double a;
    while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a)) Console.Write("a = ");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
double a;

Console.WriteLine("a = ");

while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a))
  Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели некорректное число! Введите еще раз число a");
```