# Как предотвратить присваивание пользователем строкового значения?

Tags: c#, калькулятор

Впервые пытаюсь сделать калькульятор на C#. Как предотвратить присваивание пользователем строкового значения переменным a и b в начале, при вводе чисел для последующих операций. Ломал голову час, не доломал. Сразу извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, я новичок.

```
        double a;
        double b;

        Console.WriteLine("Первое число");
        a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Второе число");
        b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
        Console.WriteLine("Выберите операцию '+' '-' '/' '*'");
        ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
        
        switch (key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.Subtract:
                Console.WriteLine(a - b);
                break;
                    
            case ConsoleKey.Multiply:
                Console.WriteLine(a * b);
                break;
            
            case ConsoleKey.Divide:
                if (b == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Ответа нет");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(a / b);   
                break;
           
            case ConsoleKey.Add:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a + b);
                }
                    break;
            
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Нажми хоть что-то нормальное, будь человеком!!");
                break;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: `if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var result)) { //Хорошо } else { //Плохо, повторить }`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1177539/373567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

нужно написать

```
while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a))
    Console.WriteLine("Не число, повторите ввод");
```

Comment: А как здесь работает out? Почему он с ридлайном находится в параметрах к трай парсу? Обьясните пожалуйста, я не очень понимаю

Comment: Вот тут всё подробно рассказано https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-6.0#system-double-tryparse(system-string-system-double@). Ридлайн выдаёт трайпарсу первый аргумент - строку, которую нужно попробовать преобразовать в число. 'out' - это просто модификатор, который означает, что этот аргумент (здесь a) является выходным - в теле метода (TryParse в данном случае) ему обязательно должно быть присвоено значение.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_quick_guide.htm https://qna.habr.com/q/20841 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/

Comment: Очень интересный ход. Можно последний вопрос, а !(не равно) относится только к double, или ко всему методу(double.TryParse())?

Comment: @aepot добрый ты

Comment: @RuslanSabitov это зависит от приоритета опреаций https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/. У '!' приоритет ниже, чем у '.' и '()', и поэтому операция отрицания выполняется последней и относится, соответственно, ко всему выражению 'double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a)'

Comment: @rotabor я сам с этих водосов начинал шарп учить. Там всё по делу, для новичка самое то.

Comment: @aepot Название неподходящее, особенно если другим рекомендовать

Comment: @rotabor вам показалось, но не настаиваю