# проблема, почему в пункте Б выводит всегда -10000

Tags: c#

Вот код:

```
internal class Program // A
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A ИЛИ B?");
            string param = Console.ReadLine();

            if (param == "A")
            {
                double x = 0.2, y;
                do
                {
                    y = Math.Log(x) + 1 / x;
                    Console.WriteLine("x = {0} y = {1}", x, y);
                    x += 0.1;
                } while (x <= 2);
            }
            else // Б
            {
                double xn = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()), xk = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()), y, min = -10000;
                do
                {
                    y = (1 - Math.Exp(-xn)) * Math.Cos(2 * xn);
                    if (y < min)
                        min = y;
                    xn += 0.1;
                } while (xn <= xk);
                Console.WriteLine("min = {0}", min);
            }


        }
    }
```

Вот по заданию сделал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ещё надо сделать проверку чтобы не крашило при вводе в консоль, например, "dgdf213", только чтобы вводить пункт 1 или 2, иначе чтобы в консоль писалось "Нет такого", или что-то похожее :)

Comment: Изначальное значение `min` какое задаете? И при каком условии оно может стать другим? Почитайте внимательно свой код.

Comment: Про ввод в консоль посмотрите это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1171427/373567, вот еще ссылка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1177539/373567

Comment: min это должно быть минимальное значение функции на фотографии пункт б)

Comment: что такое min вообще и зачем нужен он?

Comment: Это чей код вы показали выше? Свой? Тогда откуда такие вопросы?

Comment: мой, разобраться пытаюсь

Comment: Ну, и в чем проблема `min = -10000` видите? `if (y < min) min = y;` видите? Дальше надо объяснять?

Comment: это я вижу, min тогда вообще не надо?

Comment: Что ж так тяжко то. При каких условиях min останется -10000? Если условие (y < min) ни разу не выполнится, верно? То есть при прохождении от xn до xk все значения y > min.

Comment: понял спасибо))