# Помогите оптимизировать решение, узкие места покажите, не укладываюсь в время исполнения

Tags: c#, оптимизация, олимпиада

Задача пробного раунда Яндекс Контеста https://contest.yandex.ru/yacup/contest/19036/problems/E/

Сеть компании состоит из серверов, каждый из которых имеет уникальный целочисленный идентификатор.
N
пар серверов соединены друг с другом. Соединённые серверы образуют кластеры: два сервера относятся к одному и тому же кластеру, если от одного из них можно добраться до другого, перемещаясь по связям.
Периодически возникает необходимость скачать определённый файл на некоторый сервер. В сети работает сервис, аналогичный торрент-трекеру, который может сообщить, на каких серверах уже имеется необходимый файл.
Проблема, однако, заключается в том, что любой сервер может скачивать файлы только с серверов в его кластере.
Составьте программу, которая будет анализировать конфигурацию сети и сообщать, из каких источников определённый сервер может скачать необходимый файл.

**Дальше приведу скриншот, т.к. сюда некорректно вставляется**

[image: Задача]

**Вот мой код, постарался понятнее его переписать**
Логика программы такая: Считываю связи между серверами, с помощью поиска в глубину ищу среди них узлы, после считываю с консоли запросы и сразу же смотрю, есть ли они в том же кластере, что и Xi. Есть 3 идеи на оптимизацию:

1. При вводе связей сразу создавать подкластеры(A1,B1),(A2,B2)..., если A2 или B2 содержится в первом кластере то добавить B2 или A2 соответсвенно в кластер, потом ещё раз пройтись и объединить уже подкластеры, но не очень понятно как это сделать правильно, пока ещё размышляю.
2. При считывании запросов можно сначала всё считать, потом объединить одинаковые Xi, ведь в условии не сказано что они не повторяются, но тогда надо как-то будет следить за порядком вывода, что в конечном итоге мне кажется не даст существенного ускорения
3. Распараллелить программу? Кто-то в курсе, дают проверяющие машины несколько процессоров или нет?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Yandex2020_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            List< Tuple<int, int>> linkList = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
            HashSet<int> setNodes = new HashSet<int>();
            HashSet<Node> nodes = new HashSet<Node>();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                string[] nums_strings = Console.ReadLine().Split();
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(nums_strings[0]);
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(nums_strings[1]);
                linkList.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(a, b));
                setNodes.Add(a);setNodes.Add(b);
            }
            MyStopwatch stopWatch = new MyStopwatch();

            foreach (int i in setNodes) 
                nodes.Add(new Node(i));
            foreach(Tuple<int, int> tuple in linkList)
            {
                Node node = nodes.Where(p=>p.Name==tuple.Item1).ToList()[0];
                node.AddChildren(nodes.Where(p => p.Name == tuple.Item2).ToList()[0]);
            }
            DepthFirstSearch dFS = new DepthFirstSearch();
            HashSet<HashSet<int>> clusters=new HashSet<HashSet<int>>(); //Сет кластеров
            Node nodeSearch= nodes.Where(x => !dFS.visited.Contains(x)).ToList().FirstOrDefault(); 
            while(nodeSearch!=null)
            {
                clusters.Add(dFS.DFS(nodeSearch));
                nodeSearch = nodes.Where(x => !dFS.visited.Contains(x)).ToList().FirstOrDefault();//берём первый непосещённый узел
            }
            int q = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            List<string> outS= new List<string>();
          
        
             //поиск принадлежности к кластерам
            for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
            {
                string[] nums_strings = Console.ReadLine().Split();
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(nums_strings[0]);

                //ищем кластер в котором сервер, на который нужно скачать
                HashSet<int> cluster = clusters.Where(x => x.Contains(a)).ToList()[0];
                nums_strings = Console.ReadLine().Split();
                int k = 0;
                string temp = "";

                //записываем все сервера, к которым есть доступ сразу в строку для вывода
                foreach (string s in nums_strings)
                {
                    if (cluster.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(s)))
                    {
                        k++;
                        temp += s+" ";
                    }
                }
                outS.Add(k.ToString()+" " + temp.Trim());
            }
           

            foreach (string s in outS)
                Console.WriteLine(s);


        }

        


    }


    public class MyStopwatch:Stopwatch
    {
        List<string> line =new List<string>();
        public void Rec(string name)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = Elapsed;
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
            line.Add(name + ": RunTime " + elapsedTime);
        }
        public void Write()
        {
            foreach(string s in line)
                Console.WriteLine(s);  
        }
       
    }


    class Node :  IComparable<Node>
    {
        /// Имя вершины.
        public int Name { get; }
        /// Список соседних вершин.
        public List<Node> Children { get; }

        public Node(int name)
        {
            Name = name;
            Children = new List<Node>();
        }

        /// Добавляет новую соседнюю вершину.
        /// bidirect->Неориентированое ребро
        public Node AddChildren(Node node, bool bidirect = true)
        {
            Children.Add(node);
            if (bidirect)
            {
                node.Children.Add(this);
            }
            return this;
        }
        public int CompareTo(Node comparePart)
        {
            // A null value means that this object is greater.
            if (comparePart == null)
                return 1;

            else
                return this.Name.CompareTo(comparePart.Name);
        }
    }

    //обход 
    class DepthFirstSearch
    {
        // Список посещенных вершин
        public HashSet<Node> visited= new HashSet<Node>();
        // Путь из начальной вершины в целевую.
        private HashSet<int> path;

        public HashSet<int> DFS(Node start)
        {
            path = new HashSet<int>();
            Search(start);
            path.Add(start.Name);
            return path;
        }

        private bool Search(Node node)
        {
           
            visited.Add(node);
            foreach (var child in node.Children.Where(x => !visited.Contains(x)))
            {
                Search(child);
                path.Add(child.Name);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Новый вариант

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Yandex2020_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            List< Tuple<int, int>> linkList = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
            HashSet<int> setNodes = new HashSet<int>();
            HashSet<Node> nodes = new HashSet<Node>();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                string[] nums_strings = Console.ReadLine().Split();
                int a = int.Parse(nums_strings[0]);
                int b = int.Parse(nums_strings[1]);
                linkList.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(a, b));
                setNodes.Add(a);setNodes.Add(b);
            }

            foreach (int i in setNodes) 
                nodes.Add(new Node(i));
            foreach(Tuple<int, int> tuple in linkList)
            {
                Node node = nodes.Where(p=>p.Name==tuple.Item1).First();
                node.AddChildren(nodes.Where(p => p.Name == tuple.Item2).First());
            }
            DepthFirstSearch dFS = new DepthFirstSearch();
            HashSet<HashSet<int>> clusters=new HashSet<HashSet<int>>(); //Сет кластеров
            Node nodeSearch= nodes.Where(x => !dFS.visited.Contains(x)).FirstOrDefault(); 
            while(nodeSearch!=null)
            {
                clusters.Add(dFS.DFS(nodeSearch));
                nodeSearch = nodes.Where(x => !dFS.visited.Contains(x)).FirstOrDefault();//берём первый непосещённый узел
            }
            int q = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            List<string> outS= new List<string>();                                 
          
        
             //поиск принадлежности к кластерам
            for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
            {
                int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine().Split()[0]);

                //ищем кластер в котором сервер, на который нужно скачать
                HashSet<int> cluster = clusters.Where(x => x.Contains(a)).ToList().First();
                string[] nums_strings = Console.ReadLine().Split();
                int k = 0;
                string temp = "";

                //записываем все сервера, к которым есть доступ сразу в строку для вывода
                foreach (string s in nums_strings)
                {
                    if (cluster.Contains(int.Parse(s)))
                    {
                        k++;
                        temp += s+" ";
                    }
                }
                outS.Add(k+" " + temp.Trim());
            }

           
            foreach (string s in outS)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, s));
           

        }




    }



    class Node :  IComparable<Node>
    {
        /// Имя вершины.
        public int Name { get; }
        /// Список соседних вершин.
        public List<Node> Children { get; }

        public Node(int name)
        {
            Name = name;
            Children = new List<Node>();
        }

        /// Добавляет новую соседнюю вершину.
        /// bidirect->Неориентированое ребро
        public Node AddChildren(Node node, bool bidirect = true)
        {
            Children.Add(node);
            if (bidirect)
            {
                node.Children.Add(this);
            }
            return this;
        }
        public int CompareTo(Node comparePart)
        {
            // A null value means that this object is greater.
            if (comparePart == null)
                return 1;

            else
                return this.Name.CompareTo(comparePart.Name);
        }
    }

    //обход 
    class DepthFirstSearch
    {
        // Список посещенных вершин
        public HashSet<Node> visited= new HashSet<Node>();
        // Путь из начальной вершины в целевую.
        private HashSet<int> path;

        public HashSet<int> DFS(Node start)
        {
            path = new HashSet<int>();
            Search(start);
            path.Add(start.Name);
            return path;
        }

        private bool Search(Node node)
        {
           
            visited.Add(node);
            foreach (var child in node.Children.Where(x => !visited.Contains(x)))
            {
                Search(child);
                path.Add(child.Name);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Вот такой паттерн `foreach (string s in outS) Console.WriteLine(s);` можно преобразовать в вот такой `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, outS)`. Но это на ваш вкус, просто делюсь. Плюс преобразования в том, что вызов операции вывода в консоль будет один, а не много. Минус в том, что в памяти появится большая строка, содержащая все строки из массива. 2) `Convert.ToInt32` можно заменить на `int.Parse` в вашем случае, потому что исходные данные - `string`.

Comment: 3) `nodes.Where(..).ToList()[0]` можно заменить на `nodes.Where(...).First()` 4) `int q = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` - посмотрите [безотказный ввод числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1171427/373567), можно сделать красиво. 5) `outS.Add(k.ToString()+" " + temp.Trim());` - в операциях конкатенации вызывать явно `.ToString()` не нужно, он будет вызван неявно автоматически.

Comment: 6) `.ToList().FirstOrDefault()` тоже можно заменить на `.FirstOrDefault()`. Работать должно быстрее.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, по некоторым пунктам:
1) Я как увидел подумал что вот он корень зла, но оказывается нет, по времени не выигрывается практически
2) на тесте для миллиарда итераций результат 19.79 18.42 соответственно, т.е. 7 % примерно, тоже не плохо
За остальное спасибо тоже, но всё равно не хватает времени, кажется проблема в самой концепции. Теперь как ни странно памяти меньше ест,
было TL 1.58s 23.09Mb  теперь 1.586s 21.95Mb
Памяти там вообще с запасом у меня я вижу, 256 мб же по условиям доступно

Comment: Покажите обновленный код, в котором вы учли все вышеперечисленное, ну из того что решили учесть, подумаем еще. Код можете дописать в вопрос новым блоком, а не заменять старый. Подпишите только для всех, что это обновленный код.

Comment: @aepot добавил, заодно убрал лишний отладочный код

Comment: `foreach (string s in outS) Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, s));` ахаха? вот так надо: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, outS));`, без цикла :)

Comment: не очень вчитывался но можно оптимизировать немножечко если зарезервировать некое количество ячеек в листе наперед. Лист не будет пересоздаватьс в памяти и не будет тратить на єто время. `var list = new List<int>(n);`

Comment: @aepot аа, ну чёт я так себе переписал значит, невнимательность) Но с таким вариантом всё ж проблема остаётся, только попробовал)

Comment: а еще важным нюансом что время нужно засекать НА РЕЛИЗ БИЛДЕ. Не на дебаге. На дебаге время будет отличаться весьма сильно от релиза. Так что возможно ты уже вклиниваешся во время.

Comment: @Andrew дело не в билде, а в опции `optimize code` в конфигурации сборки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы используете циклы в цикле - то есть сложность вашего алгоритма квадратичная.

Вот это вообще нельзя делать `Node node = nodes.Where(p=>p.Name==tuple.Item1).First()` если вам надо искать по имени, для этого есть соотвествующие  структуры данных.

---

Представим все отношения вершин словарем. Словать для каждой вершины хранит все связанные с ней вершины.

```
var relations = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>();
```

Метод, чтобы добавить связь в словарь

```
private void AddConnection(int first, int second, 
                           Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>> relations)
{
    if (relations.ContainsKey(first)) relations[first].Add(second);
    else relations[first] = new HashSet<int>() { second };

    if (relations.ContainsKey(second)) relations[second].Add(first);
    else relations[second] = new HashSet<int>() { first };
}
```

Добавим связи (вот если бы вы дали возможность копипастить числа на входе и выходе, вы бы облешчили всем задачу, а так получаете просто хардкод)

```
AddConnection(545, 993, relations);
AddConnection(796, 545, relations);
AddConnection(645, 993, relations);
AddConnection(565, 645, relations);
AddConnection(271, 814, relations);
AddConnection(894, 271, relations);
AddConnection(937, 814, relations);
AddConnection(898, 937, relations);
```

Имея связи, создадим словать для связных компонент - вот такой. Этот словарь для каждой вершины сопоставляет число - идентификатор связной компоненты.

```
var components = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

Для заполнения используем простейший вариант поиска в ширину. Хоть и кажется, что тут цикл в цикле, но на самом деле каждая вершина тут будет обработана 1 раз, то есть скорость этого алгоритма линейная.

```
private void BuildComponents(Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>> relations, 
                              Dictionary<int, int> components)
{
    int componentCount = 0;

    foreach (var key in relations.Keys)
    {
        if (components.ContainsKey(key)) continue;
        componentCount++;

        var q = new Queue<int>();
        q.Enqueue(key);
        components[key] = componentCount;

        while (q.Count > 0)
        {
            var item = q.Dequeue();             
            if (relations.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                foreach (var relation in relations[item])
                {
                    if (components.ContainsKey(relation)) continue;
                    q.Enqueue(relation);
                    components[relation] = componentCount;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вызывем метод

```
BuildComponents(relations, components);
```

Теперь, чтобы понять, можно ли с какого то сервера скачать на какой то дргугой - достаточно проверить, что они оба в одной компоненте. Пара примеров:

```
foreach (var source in new[] {937, 796}){
    if (components[source] == components[565])
        Console.WriteLine($"{565} - {source}");
}

foreach (var source in new[] { 645, 565 })
{
    if (components[source] == components[993])
        Console.WriteLine($"{993} - {source}");
}
```

Вывод ожидаем

```
565 - 796
993 - 645
993 - 565
```

Answer (score 0):

Эту задачу можно решать с помощью структуры данных "лес (или система) непересекающихся множеств", disjoint sets.

При вводе связей выполняется алгоритм union-find, серверы объединяются в куст, имеющий одного представителя.

При вводе запросов проверяется, что серверы с файлом принадлежат к тому же кусту, что и сервер-приёмник, т.е. их представители совпадают с представителем приёмника.

Реализация операций очень простая и весьма эффективная