# C# Вложенный switch. На втором switch в переменную записывается какая-то переменная

Tags: c#, switch

При выборе действия в первом switch, переходит ко второму, не дает два раза ввести данные с клавиатуры, переходя в блок default. В чем может быть проблема?

То есть я вижу:

```
Выберите таблицу:
1. Гости
2. Номера
3. Заселение
4. Категории намеров
5. Стоимость номеров
1
Выбрана таблица 'Гости'
Выберите действие:
1. Создать (CREATE)
2. Вывод (READ / SELECT)
3. Обновить (UPDATE)
4. Удалить (DELETE)
0. Назад (BACK)
Незивестная команда
Выберите действие:
1. Создать (CREATE)
2. Вывод (READ / SELECT)
3. Обновить (UPDATE)
4. Удалить (DELETE)
0. Назад (BACK)
Незивестная команда
Выберите действие:
1. Создать (CREATE)
2. Вывод (READ / SELECT)
3. Обновить (UPDATE)
4. Удалить (DELETE)
0. Назад (BACK)
```

А должно быть:

```
Выберите таблицу:
1. Гости
2. Номера
3. Заселение
4. Категории намеров
5. Стоимость номеров
1
Выбрана таблица 'Гости'
Выберите действие:
1. Создать (CREATE)
2. Вывод (READ / SELECT)
3. Обновить (UPDATE)
4. Удалить (DELETE)
0. Назад (BACK)
```

Далее код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Kursovaya
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SelectTable();
        }
        public static void SelectTable()
        {
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Выберите таблицу: ");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Гости");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Номера");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Заселение");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Категории намеров");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Стоимость номеров");
            int table = Console.Read();

            switch (table)
            {
                case '1':
                    Console.WriteLine("Выбрана таблица 'Гости'");
                    SelectAction();
                    break;
                case '2':
                    SelectAction();
                    break;
                case '3':
                    SelectAction();
                    break;
                case '4':
                    SelectAction();
                    break;
                case '5':
                    SelectAction();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Незивестная команда");
                    SelectTable();
                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void SelectAction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Выберите действие: ");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Создать (CREATE)");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Вывод (READ / SELECT)");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Обновить (UPDATE)");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Удалить (DELETE)");
            Console.WriteLine("0. Назад (BACK)");

            int action = Console.Read();
            switch (action)
            {
                case '1':

                    break;
                case '2':
                    break;
                case '3':
                    break;
                case '4':
                    break;
                case '0':
                    SelectTable();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Незивестная команда");
                    SelectAction();
                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите часть "пользовательский интерфейс" в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1171427/373567) и избавьтесь от рекурсивных вызовов.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте ReadLine вместо Read:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SelectTable();
    }
    public static void SelectTable()
    {
        //Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Выберите таблицу: ");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Гости");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Номера");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Заселение");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Категории намеров");
        Console.WriteLine("5. Стоимость номеров");
        string table = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (table)
        {
            case "1":
                Console.WriteLine("Выбрана таблица 'Гости'");
                SelectAction();
                break;
            case "2":
                SelectAction();
                break;
            case "3":
                SelectAction();
                break;
            case "4":
                SelectAction();
                break;
            case "5":
                SelectAction();
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Незивестная команда");
                SelectTable();
                break;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void SelectAction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Выберите действие: ");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Создать (CREATE)");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Вывод (READ / SELECT)");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Обновить (UPDATE)");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Удалить (DELETE)");
        Console.WriteLine("0. Назад (BACK)");

        string action = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (action)
        {
            case "1":

                break;
            case "2":
                break;
            case "3":
                break;
            case "4":
                break;
            case "0":
                SelectTable();
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Незивестная команда");
                SelectAction();
                break;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
    }
}
```

После ReadLine программа останавливается и ждёт пока вы не введёте строку и не нажмёте Enter. При Read читается текущее (мгновенное) состояние нажатых клавиш и идёт дальнейшее выполнение программы. Ваш код Read возвращает -1 если не нажата ни одна клавиша (так обычно и происходит), поэтому вы и попадаете в секцию default.

Comment: Здесь надо избавиться от двойной рекурсии, она ни к чему хорошему не приведет.

Comment: @aepot Очень хорошее замечание, я видя что явная домашка не вглядывался пристально что ещё в этом коде стоит улучшить.