# Помогите пожалуйста, как запустить в статическом методе не статический

Tags: c#

Задание такое, используя списки `List` написать программу "Записная книжка", и я не уверен в качестве своего кода, и не могу обойти проблему с использованием не статических методов. Как мне запустить метод `Menu` в `Main`? (код не дописан, так как мне помешала эта проблема, я пытался обойти с помощью класса, но как видно в коде, это тоже не вышло)

```
class Program
{
    public class RecordingData
    {
        public string Data;
        public List<Recording> listRecording = new List<Recording>();
        public RecordingData(string data, int n1, string rt1, string t1, string d1)
        {
            Data = data;
            listRecording.Add(new Recording(n1, rt1, t1, d1));
        }
    }

    public class Recording
    {
        public int Number;
        public string RecordType;
        public string Time;
        public string Description;

        public Recording(int n, string rt, string t, string d)
        {

            Number = n;
            RecordType = rt;
            Time = t;
            Description = d;
        }
    }

    public List<RecordingData> notebook = new List<RecordingData>();

    public void AddRecording()
    {
        notebook.Add(new RecordingData("gdsg", 1, "214eefs", "24ewf", "fdfgdf"));
        Console.Write(notebook[0]);
    }

    public void Menu()
    {
        int Variant = 0;

        while (Variant != 5)
        {
            Console.Write($"МЕНЮ \n1. Поиск \n2. Добавить\n3. Изменить \n4. Удалить\n5. Завершить работу \nВведите цифру, соответсвующую необходимому пункту меню: ");

            Variant = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (Variant == 1)
            {

            }
            else
                if (Variant == 2)
            {
                AddRecording();
            }
            else
                if (Variant == 3)
            {

            }
            else
                if (Variant == 4)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public class ClassMenu
    {
        public  void StartMenu ()
        {
            Menu();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassMenu start = new ClassMenu();
        start.StartMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: Есть много примеров, как сделать меню в консоли, [вот один из них](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1171427/373567)

Comment: Ну в начале реализую остальные функции, а потом поколдую над меню) спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы вызвать метод объекта, надо создать этот объект.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program program = new Program();
    program.Menu();
}
```

Еще, у вас есть недочет, который может помешать в будущем, вы описываете новые классы внутри класса `Program`, не делайте так, описывайте снаружи, рядом с классом, а не внутри него. На их доступность это никак не повлияет.

Comment: Так у меня так и сделано, но не работает

Comment: @НиколайСинев насколько я вижу, у вас сделано по-другому. Я не вижу у вас ни одного вызова конструктора `new Program()`.

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassMenu start = new ClassMenu();
        start.StartMenu();
    }
Может я что то не понимаю?

Comment: @НиколайСинев а если внимательнее посмотреть, то можно увидеть, что между `ClassMenu` и `Program` таки есть разница.

Comment: АААААААААААААААААААААААААААА меня только осенило, сейчас попробую

Comment: @НиколайСинев берете метод `Main` из ответа, копируете себе в код вместо своего, оно начинает работать, ставите моему ответу галочку, и дело с концом.

Comment: Работает, пока что как минимум, спасибо, ты лучший)) 
Только можешь по подробнее объяснить, как и почему?
А ещё спасибо за совет про написание класса до класса программ )

Comment: @НиколайСинев `как и почему?` - потому что ООП. Чтобы включить чайник, надо его создать. Класс - это чертеж чайника, а не сам чайник. А вы чтобы включить чайник создали чашку, дергаете ее за ручку, чайник не включается. Как-то так.

Comment: Чуть не уссался от метафоры на чайник) хахахахах

Answer (score -1):

Если коротко, то никак.

ClassMenu является дочерним и не знает, какие методы есть у родителя.

Comment: А как это исправить?

Comment: Относись к классу Program как объекту самого высокого уровня. Сделай новый класс-обертку вокруг твоих классов и в нем пиши те методы, которые тебе нужны. Класс-обертка должен принимать решение о показе, а не меню.

Comment: Да хоть как можно к этому объекту относиться можно, но если не создать экземпляр, невозможно будет вызвать ни одного нестатичного метода.

Comment: А поподробнее для тупеньких

Comment: Просто перенеси всю реализацию в ClassMenu