# C# - Как разделить построчно полученные строки

Tags: c#

Имеется такой генератор паролей. Но когда программа доходит до вывода количества полученных паролей, то они соединяются вместе. (Пример: программа сделала 2 пароля '123' и '321', но результат выходит, как '123321'). Как можно разделить эти пароли под каждую новую строку?

````
using System.Text;

public class Passgen
{
    public static string GetRandomPassword(int length)
    {
        int amount = 0;
        const string digits = "0123456789";
        const string smalleng = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        const string capitaleng = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        const string smallrus = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
        const string capitalrus = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
        const string smalleng_smallrus = smalleng + smallrus;
        const string capitaleng_capitalrus = capitaleng + capitalrus;
        const string special = "!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_'{|}~ ";


        Console.WriteLine("Выберите тип паролей: ");
        Console.WriteLine("1) Цифры ");
        Console.WriteLine("2) Анг + Рус алфавиты в нижнем регистре ");
        Console.WriteLine("3) Анг алфавит в нижнем регистре ");
        Console.WriteLine("4) Рус алфавит в нижнем регистре ");
        Console.WriteLine("5) Анг + Рус алфавиты в верхнем регистре ");
        Console.WriteLine("6) Анг алфавит в верхнем регистре ");
        Console.WriteLine("7) Рус алфавит в верхнем регистре ");
        Console.WriteLine("8) Специальные символы ");
        int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Количество паролей = ");
        amount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        if (choice == 1)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(digits.Length);
                    sb.Append(digits[index]);
                }
            
            }
        }

        if (choice == 2)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(smalleng_smallrus.Length);
                    sb.Append(smalleng_smallrus[index]);
                }
            }
        }

        if (choice == 3)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(smalleng.Length);
                    sb.Append(smalleng[index]);
                }
            }
        }

        if (choice == 4)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(smallrus.Length);
                    sb.Append(smallrus[index]);
                }
            }
        }

        if (choice == 5)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(capitaleng_capitalrus.Length);
                    sb.Append(capitaleng_capitalrus[index]);
                }
            }
        }

        if (choice == 6)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(capitaleng.Length);
                    sb.Append(capitaleng[index]);
                }
            }
        }

        if (choice == 7)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(capitalrus.Length);
                    sb.Append(capitalrus[index]);
                }
            }
        }

        if (choice == 8)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(special.Length);
                    sb.Append(special[index]);
                }
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        begin: Console.Write("Длина паролей = ");
        int length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        if (length < 6) { Console.WriteLine("Длина паролей должна быть больше либо равна 6! Введите значение заново"); goto begin; }


        
        string password = GetRandomPassword(length);
        Console.WriteLine(password);
        
    }
} ```
````

Comment: В коллекцию добавляйте каждую строку и всё, потом можно будет склеить элементы в строку каким-нибудь string.Join

Comment: @Aarnihauta Зачем такие сложности? Почитайте доки по SB.

Comment: @aepot видимо вопрос неправильно понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос выглядит так

```
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
    {
        int index = rnd.Next(digits.Length);
        sb.Append(digits[index]);
    }
    sb.AppendLine();
}
```

Но у вас очень много повторяющегося кода. Обратите внимание на то, в скольких местах вам надо поправить код, чтобы внести предложенное мной решение в свой код? А должно быть в одном. Давайте исправим это.

Для начала, вынести генерацию пароля в отдельный метод, тогда код получится такой.

```
private static readonly Random rnd = new Random();

private static string GeneratePassword(string chars, int amount, int length)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
        {
            int index = rnd.Next(chars.Length);
            sb.Append(chars[index]);
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

public static string GetRandomPassword(int length)
{
    int amount = 0;
    const string digits = "0123456789";
    const string smalleng = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const string capitaleng = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    const string smallrus = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
    const string capitalrus = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
    const string smalleng_smallrus = smalleng + smallrus;
    const string capitaleng_capitalrus = capitaleng + capitalrus;
    const string special = "!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_'{|}~ ";


    Console.WriteLine("Выберите тип паролей: ");
    Console.WriteLine("1) Цифры ");
    Console.WriteLine("2) Анг + Рус алфавиты в нижнем регистре ");
    Console.WriteLine("3) Анг алфавит в нижнем регистре ");
    Console.WriteLine("4) Рус алфавит в нижнем регистре ");
    Console.WriteLine("5) Анг + Рус алфавиты в верхнем регистре ");
    Console.WriteLine("6) Анг алфавит в верхнем регистре ");
    Console.WriteLine("7) Рус алфавит в верхнем регистре ");
    Console.WriteLine("8) Специальные символы ");
    int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Количество паролей = ");
    amount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    string result = "";

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        result = GeneratePassword(digits, amount, length);
    }

    if (choice == 2)
    {
        result = GeneratePassword(smalleng_smallrus, amount, length);
    }

    if (choice == 3)
    {
        result = GeneratePassword(smalleng, amount, length);
    }

    if (choice == 4)
    {
        result = GeneratePassword(smallrus, amount, length);
    }

    if (choice == 5)
    {
        result = GeneratePassword(capitaleng_capitalrus, amount, length);
    }

    if (choice == 6)
    {
        result = GeneratePassword(capitaleng, amount, length);
    }

    if (choice == 7)
    {
        result = GeneratePassword(capitalrus, amount, length);
    }

    if (choice == 8)
    {
        result = GeneratePassword(special, amount, length);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Но все еще много повторяющегося кода, продолжим. Можно объединить константы в массив, тогда к константе можно будет обратиться по индексу в массиве, а не только по имени.

```
public static string GetRandomPassword(int length)
{
    const string digits = "0123456789";
    const string smalleng = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const string capitaleng = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    const string smallrus = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
    const string capitalrus = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
    const string smalleng_smallrus = smalleng + smallrus;
    const string capitaleng_capitalrus = capitaleng + capitalrus;
    const string special = "!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_'{|}~ ";

    string[] dictionaries = new string[]
    {
        digits,
        smalleng,
        capitaleng,
        smallrus,
        capitalrus,
        smalleng_smallrus,
        capitaleng_capitalrus,
        special
    };

    Console.WriteLine("Выберите тип паролей: ");
    Console.WriteLine("1) Цифры ");
    Console.WriteLine("2) Анг + Рус алфавиты в нижнем регистре ");
    Console.WriteLine("3) Анг алфавит в нижнем регистре ");
    Console.WriteLine("4) Рус алфавит в нижнем регистре ");
    Console.WriteLine("5) Анг + Рус алфавиты в верхнем регистре ");
    Console.WriteLine("6) Анг алфавит в верхнем регистре ");
    Console.WriteLine("7) Рус алфавит в верхнем регистре ");
    Console.WriteLine("8) Специальные символы ");
    int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Количество паролей = ");
    int amount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (choice >= 1 && choice <= 8)
    {
        return GeneratePassword(dictionaries[choice - 1], amount, length);
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще один способ:

```
using System.Text;
using System;
public class Passgen
{
    public static string GetRandomPassword(int length)
    {
        int amount = 0;
        const string digits = "0123456789";
        const string smalleng = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        const string capitaleng = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        const string smallrus = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
        const string capitalrus = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
        const string smalleng_smallrus = smalleng + smallrus;
        const string capitaleng_capitalrus = capitaleng + capitalrus;
        const string special = "!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_'{|}~ ";


        Console.WriteLine("Выберите тип паролей: ");
        Console.WriteLine("1) Цифры ");
        Console.WriteLine("2) Анг + Рус алфавиты в нижнем регистре ");
        Console.WriteLine("3) Анг алфавит в нижнем регистре ");
        Console.WriteLine("4) Рус алфавит в нижнем регистре ");
        Console.WriteLine("5) Анг + Рус алфавиты в верхнем регистре ");
        Console.WriteLine("6) Анг алфавит в верхнем регистре ");
        Console.WriteLine("7) Рус алфавит в верхнем регистре ");
        Console.WriteLine("8) Специальные символы ");
        int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Количество паролей = ");
        amount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        if (choice == 1)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(digits.Length);
                    sb.Append(digits[index]);
                }
                sb.Append('\n');
            
            }
        }

        if (choice == 2)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(smalleng_smallrus.Length);
                    sb.Append(smalleng_smallrus[index]);
                }
                sb.Append('\n');
            }
        }

        if (choice == 3)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(smalleng.Length);
                    sb.Append(smalleng[index]);
                }
            }
        }

        if (choice == 4)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(smallrus.Length);
                    sb.Append(smallrus[index]);
                }
                sb.Append('\n');
            }
        }

        if (choice == 5)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(capitaleng_capitalrus.Length);
                    sb.Append(capitaleng_capitalrus[index]);
                }
                sb.Append('\n');
            }
        }

        if (choice == 6)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(capitaleng.Length);
                    sb.Append(capitaleng[index]);
                }
                sb.Append('\n');
            }
        }

        if (choice == 7)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(capitalrus.Length);
                    sb.Append(capitalrus[index]);
                }
                sb.Append('\n');
            }
        }

        if (choice == 8)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
                {
                    int index = rnd.Next(special.Length);
                    sb.Append(special[index]);
                }
                sb.Append('\n');
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Длина паролей = ");
        int length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        while (length < 6)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Длина паролей должна быть больше либо равна 6! Введите значение заново"); 
            Console.Write("Длина паролей = ");
            length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        
        string password = GetRandomPassword(length);
        Console.WriteLine(password);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот, о чем я и говорил, вы пропустили 3 вариант, забыли внести правку в код. Но обратите внимание, что если в `\n` сработает в консоли, то он не сработает например в текстбоксе Windorms, вместо `\n` используйте `Environment.NewLine` тогда точно не ошибетесь. Либо как я предложил `.AppendLine()`;

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1171427/373567) "Безотказный ввод числа", там используется делегат (предикат), незнакомая вам пока сущность, но наглядно показано, как оно работает. Это поможет еще улучшить код.