# Построение треугольника через цикл for

Tags: c#

хочу сделать треугольник перевернутый сверху, вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но у меня вышло только это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

кто направит на путь истинный, в чем моя ошибка? половина треугольника из пятерок вроде бы правильна

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] a = new int[10, 10];

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    a[i, j] = 1;
                }
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                if (j < 5)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < j + 1; i++)
                    {
                        a[i, j] = 5;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = j; i < j + 1; i++)
                    {
                        a[i, j] = 6;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(a[i,j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1171427/373567

Comment: Обратите внимание, где у вас `i` в циклах, а где у вас `j`.

Comment: !(https://sun9-85.userapi.com/impf/-CbJxOa0Rm2zAZr2p3yjAE_iZBLbgQefCtuZTg/yWOdNNGRTnk.jpg?size=624x348&quality=96&sign=3d96da691fc77061b73091a88f935aeb&type=album)

Comment: это по примеру из вопроса 1171220, не то, если никто не поможет, придётся думать и долго :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (j >= i && 10 - j > i) Console.Write(5);
        else Console.Write(1);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

```
5555555555
1555555551
1155555511
1115555111
1111551111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
```

Comment: спасибо!! всё супер
https://sun9-60.userapi.com/impf/Re2bCnj0fGfuLnXTvpt2B-ALAR-iX-tOes7Rmg/eIlhfybkqKA.jpg?size=818x520&quality=96&sign=67c0c36163ed98af1a421fd1a0239b54&type=album

Comment: @aepot да-да, я пытался, пишет "Вы можете принять ответ через 3 минуты", обязательно нажму :))