# Почему пропускается ввод переменной?

Tags: c#

Пишу программу, которая сравнивает строку из текстового файла с строкой, введенной с клавиатуры. Но при первом проходе в цикле игнорируется строка ввода (пометил комментарием), после первой итерации ввод работает корректно. С чем это может быть связано?

P.S. Тестирую на английском, т.к. не знаю немецкого.

```
class Program
{
    public static string PathSetRus()
    {
        string a;
        Console.WriteLine("Введите путь для файла русских слов:");
        a = Console.ReadLine();
        return a;
    }
    public static string PathSetGer()
    {
        string a;
        Console.WriteLine("Введите путь для файла немецких слов:");
        a = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        return a;
    }
    public bool IsValid(char ch)
    {
        if (ch < '1' | ch > '2') return true;
        else return false;
    }
    public static bool TrCh()
    {
        bool flag=true;
        char ins;
        Program y = new Program();
        try
        {
            for(; ; )
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Выберите режим перевода (1 или 2):\n1.Русский-Немецкий\n2.Немецкий-Русский");
                    do
                    {
                        ins = (char)Console.Read();
                    }
                    while (ins == '\n' | ins == '\r');
                }
                while (y.IsValid(ins));
                Console.WriteLine();
                switch (ins)
                {
                    case ('1'):
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    case ('2'):
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                }
                break;
            }
            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
        }
        return flag;
    }

 static void Main()
    {
        string r = PathSetRus(); //Путь для рус.слов
        string g = PathSetGer(); //Путь для нем.слов

        bool f = TrCh(); //Выбранный режим перевода

        string line1 = "", line2, ans = "";

        if (f)
        {
            try
            {

                //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
                StreamReader rus = new StreamReader(r);
                StreamReader ger = new StreamReader(g);
                while (line1 != null)
                {
                    //Read the line of text
                    line1 = rus.ReadLine();
                    line2 = ger.ReadLine();

                    while ((line1 != null) && (ans != line2))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Переведите на немецкий слово " + line1);
                        ans = Console.ReadLine(); //Строка игнорируется при первой итерации
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        if (ans != line2)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка,попробуйте еще");
                            Console.WriteLine();
                        }
                    }

                }
                rus.Close();
                ger.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Вы отлично поработали!");
            }
        }
```

Консоль выглядит так:
[image: Консоль]

Comment: `TrCh()` покажите этот метод, проблема в нем

Comment: Добавил, остальные методы тоже написал на всякий случай.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в методе `TRch`, он невычищает буфер клавы после себя и перенос строки попадает в следующий ридлайн.

Плюс он сложный и немного запутан, я переписал на попроще:

```
public static bool TrCh()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Выберите режим перевода (1 или 2):\n1.Русский-Немецкий\n2.Немецкий-Русский");
    char input = '\0';
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            input = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;
            switch (input)
            {
                case '1':
                    return true;
                case '2':
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input);
        while (Console.KeyAvailable) // чистка буфера клавы
            Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Как более гибкую альтернативу, можете посмотреть безотказный ввод числа с менюшками [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1171427/373567).