# C#, делаю консольное приложение, выбор цифрами, хочу сопоставить цифры и соответствующие цифрам ответы в формате строк через Enum. Это возможно?

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("Выберите занятие:\n" +
                "1.Сон\n" +
                "2.Тренировка\n" +
                "3.Универ\n" +
                "4.Отдых\n" +
                "5.Домашка");
```

Хочу сделать максимально краткий код.

Comment: как именно это сделает код короче?

Comment: Enum можно привязать к конкретным словам использую ToString(). [Пример](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tostring?view=net-7.0). Максимально краткий код не лучшая идея.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1171427/373567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короткий код - не всегда означает правильный код. В вашем же случае лучше сделать так:

1. Создаёте абстрактный класс AbstractTask, в котором есть свойства `int ID`, `string Name`, конструктор для них и метод `Invoke`.
2. Создаёте для каждого действия свой экземпляр (конструктор должен быть пустой, лишь с вызовом инструктора базового класса через base(0, "Your Task Title")), `SleepTask`, `TrainingTask` и.т.д

Далее в месте проверки вставляете код:

```
List<AbstractTask> tasks = new List<AbstractTask>()
{
   new SleepTask(),
   new TrainingTask(),
};

int id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

AbstractTask? selectedTask = tasks.Find(z => z.ID == id);
if(selectedTask != null)
   selectedTask.Invoke();
```